# jQuery calls twice a function

Tags: jquery

When i click the .kontrahent div i want to use another jquery function to load xml document and append it to #info div, but when i click it get's called twice, i have no idea why it's not working. I have checked delegate,live,click and on methods.

jQuery code:

```
$("#dane").on('click',".kontrahent",function(){
   console.log($(this));
   var konh_id = $(this).data("konhid");
   show_info(konh_id);
   $('#info').show();
});
```

Html code

```
<div class="row">
  <div id="dane" class="span6">
    <div class="kontrahent">
    </div>
    <div class="kontrahent">
    </div>
    <div class="kontrahent">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="info" class="span8">TESTOWE INFORMACJE O KLIENCIE</div>
</div>
```

Then in console i have twice the selection

Comment: Works correctly: http://jsbin.com/iquhur You must have left something important out.

Comment: Your `show_info()` probably causes it. I commented it out (for testing), and clicking `.kontrahent` is called once.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/VmkWE/ works ok for me

Comment: Ok, Now i just had Posting Magic, i was calling script.js twice coz before i have been loading  with jquery another file. Now i corrected it and works fine :)

Comment: @Mateutek Please post you last comment into the answer field and accept your own answer as soulution.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely a bug specially while it's FireFox. I searched alot and finally got it as bug by many experts over SO. So, I finally came up with this idea by declaring variable like

```
var called = false;
$("#ColorPalete li").click(function() {
    if(called ===false)
    {
             called = true;
             setTimeout(function(){ //<-----This can be an ajax request but keep in mind to set called=false when you get response or when the function has successfully executed.
                 alert('I am called');
                 called = false;
             },3000);

    }
});
```

In this way it first checks rather the function was previously called or not.